# SASS select last element from a last element

Tags: sass, css-selectors

I have difficulties to add border to the last class="separator" from the last  class="list-group".
I want to do this in SASS. Can someone please help me, because my solution doesn't work.

HTML

```
<div class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item"></div>
    <div class="separator"></div>
</div>
<div class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item"></div>
    <div class="separator"></div>
</div>
<div class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item"></div>
    <div class="separator"></div>
</div>
<div class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item"></div>
    <div class="separator"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.list-group {
    &:last-child .separator {
        border-left: 1px solid black;
    }
 }
```

Comment: can you please add plunkr?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have an account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me there is no problem in your sass code. Just add some content into html and the browser will start showing border. Something like this

```
<div class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item"></div>
    <div class="separator">item1</div>
</div>
<div class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item"></div>
    <div class="separator">item2</div>
</div>
<div class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item"></div>
    <div class="separator">item3</div>
</div>
<div class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item"></div>
    <div class="separator">item4</div>
</div>
```

Output (for your reference):

[image: html output]

can you spot the left border on item4?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
I know it's too late xd

```
.list-group {
    .separator:last-child {
        border-left: 1px solid black;
    }
}
```